# Connection reset by peer while trying to mount sshfs in fstab

Tags: mount, fstab, sshfs

I have the following line in `fstab`

```
 sshfs#dimskraft@MYSERVER:/ /mnt/MYSERVER fuse _netdev,user,idmap=user,transform_symlinks,identityfile=/home/dimskraft/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=74583,gid=22799 0 0
```

but when I am trying to mount

```
$ sudo mount /mnt/MYSERVER
read: Connection reset by peer
```

Why and what can be done?

Comment: check your auth.log and secure.log.  also as dimskraft, make sure that the ssh fingerprint from MYSERVER has been added to your local .ssh/.known_hosts.